# Ultrafast PDFLaTeX with precompiling

Tags: compiling, automation, latexmk, preamble, format-files

I try to improve the time pdflatex needs to compile my book.

## Really working example

#### book.tex

```
%&preamble
\begin{document}
Hi
\end{document}
```

and

#### preamble.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
```

I run the following commands on bash console:

```bsh
$ pdflatex -ini -jobname="preamble" "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump"
$ latexmk -pdf -pvc -e '$latex=q/latex %O -shell-escape %S/' book.tex
```

A window opens with a (nearly) live preview that will be updated after each change in the `book.tex` file. The PDF Viewer `evince` reloads automatic when the `.pdf` changed.

## Open Questions

**I had no success to compile with the preamble of my book** in the `preamble.tex` file.

- How can I find out what I can [precompile](http://magic.aladdin.cs.cmu.edu/2007/11/02/precompiled-preamble-for-latex/)?
- Can I precompile `\newcommand`'s, `\usepackage`'s?
- Can I precompile a pure chapter without header?

## Other approaches for speed up

(I do not understand how to combine these ideas for best result)

- `pdflatex` knows a `-draftmode`
  I measured 20% faster compilation with `time pdflatex -draftmode 50pagetest.tex`

Comment: If you `\include` many chapters you can use `\includeonly` in your master file (`book.tex`) to compile just the chapters you are editing at the moment.

Comment: I guess that will include additional `\clearpage` before and afterwards

Comment: @Jonas Yes `\include` and `\includeonly` works only with separating the file's content on different pages. But for your final compilation you can change those `\includeonly` back to `\input`s. • Also related: [`mylatexformat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mylatexformat)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel mylatexformat looks interesting, but i can not understand how to use it with the short manual. It only describes the usage for MikTeX, but i run TeXLive on debian stable.

Comment: @Jonas I've never used it myself as I use MiKTeX myself … I won't be much of help here. • Also related: [How can I speed up LaTeX compilation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45) and [Speed up beamer compile time](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27351)

Comment: @JonasStein Not sure on Debian, but on MacTeX you see the options of eTeX with `etex --help`, then you can use `mylatexformat` with  `etex -ini "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx """YOURFILE.TEX""" to create the format. Then call `etex "&mylatexformat" YOURFILE`.

Comment: @JonasStein You can create a format (precompile) preloading packages, and `\newcommand`.  With `mylatexformat` you can compile files with the same preamble, the files must have a `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`

Comment: Related Question: [Custom format file: How to automate the generation of the “precompiled preamble” whenever one of the files that are used there are changed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49388/custom-format-file-how-to-automate-the-generation-of-the-precompiled-preamble).

Comment: @JonasStein: Could you post a MnWE for your (failed) separation of your `book` document into `preamble.tex` and `book.tex`? Also, what is the exact wording of the error message?

Comment: Sorry i can not give a minimal working example yet because my preamble is so large. I need first a strategy which codelines can be exported. Blind try and error strategy would take days.

Comment: You can use dichotomy search : comment out half of your preamble, see if it works, etc. That will quickly point you to the faulty package or command, even with a very large preamble.

Comment: The default `texmf` path for format files with `texlive` is `~/texmf/web2c/pdftex`, as pointed here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249026/116936)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

"precompile" is probably a slightly confusing phrase to use as TeX is not a compiler but (mostly) a macro expansion language, but anyway...

In general you can dump most macro definitions and register assignments into a format. What you can't do is ship out pages. So in practice you can dump most LaTeX preambles.

Rather than having to edit the file so that it *only* works with the preloaded preamble format it is possible to leave the preamble as normal, but define the dumped format to skip the commands that were previously executed in the dump.

My truly ancient `mylatex` files on ctan do this or there is a newer version of that with additional features and better maintained: [mylatexformat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mylatexformat)

The main thing you have to beware of (and which I suspect you are falling over) is if any of commands that you dump use `\jobname` (for example to open auxiliary files)  then you have to ensure that the jobname when you dump the format is the same as the jobname when you produce the document. Also If the macros are assuming that files opened by commands in the preamble are still open when the document is processed then you will need to re-open them when you use your preloaded format loading the format file will re-set TeX's internal state with respect to its internal memory but it will not re-assign the file handles to the filesystem.

The first hit on searching for `mylatex` on this site shows an example discussing this in the context of tikz externalize.

[TikZ's externalization and mylatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19403/tikzs-externalization-and-mylatex)

---

I wrote the above back in 2012, If writing it now I would stress two other classes of things that can not be dumped.

- OpenType fonts (so affecting any xelatex or lualatex preamble that loads system fonts), and
- Lua state, so affecting any package that uses `\directlua` if used with luatex. For any particular Lua code you can usually `\dump` a macro definition that executes the code in `\everyjob` or `\AtBeginDocument` however this often requires substantial re-arrangement of the package code, so using `mylatex` with an unchanged latex document is often not possible when using lualatex.

Comment: I definitely like leaving the preamble intact and skipping it when not needed, such as when submitting `tex` files to a publisher. However, this means that when I checkout the document from a git repo (which does not hold the `fmt` file, obviously) the document will compile fine, without any warning that a precompiled format has not been used. Is there a way for me to issue a warning if the `fmt` file has not been found? I could maybe check for the existence of the `fmt` file, but is there a more "internal" approach to this?

Comment: @bers `\IFFileExists{\jobname.fmt}{....}{...}` ?

Comment: yes, this is what I ended up doing. I had been looking for something that ensures not only that the file exists, but that it has been used, too. I have now added `\ifcsname endofdump\endcsname\else\PackageWarning{mylatexformat}{Precompiled header not used}\fi`.

Answer (score 26):

For the benefit of people using a search engine arriving here looking for how to convert a never-changing but slow-loading preamble into a super-quick "precompiled" format.

The [instructions here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160712215709/http://www.howtotex.com:80/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-iv-use-a-precompiled-preamble/) take you through a simple process, as follows. You need the [`mylatexformat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mylatexformat) package to make this work.

1. Split your preamble into "static" and "might change" stuff, with the static stuff first.
2. At the end of the static stuff add the command `\endofdump`
3. Run the following from the command line/terminal, replacing *both instances* of `foo` with the name of your document:

   ```bash
   pdftex -ini -jobname="foo" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx foo.tex
   ```
4. Insert the code `%&foo` at the top of your `.tex` file, replacing `foo` with the name of your file.

Your compiles will now happen *much* faster.

*Note: if you have any "might change" preamble, you need to keep the `\endofdump` command, otherwise compilation will start at `\begin{document}` skipping all your preamble.*

Comment: Step 4 (deleting the precompiled preamble) is not needed. The generated format loads `mylatexformat` which skips content until \endofdump. Viceversa, if you're ready to delete content, you needn't `mylatexformat`, you just need to use the `\dump` command as explained here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20170718172440/http://7fttallrussian.blogspot.it/2010/02/speed-up-latex-compilation.html

Comment: @Blaisorblade wow, this really makes the workflow much, MUCH simpler. Love it.

Comment: Thanks! Meanwhile, I've taken https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37730/1340, dropped `mylatexformat`, adapted it a bit (sorry, not published yet) and now get the prelude auto-recompiled by latexmk on changes (though it need be a separate file for that), which seems even better (YMMV)!

Comment: To save time for future visitors, note that this doesn't work with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49295/precompile-header-with-xelatex (loaded OTF fonts can't be dumped, and most big packages load OTF fonts)

Answer (score 4):

In this answer I will explain how does "precompiled preamble" works, how to use it in PDFLaTeX/XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX, as well as some pitfalls.

Normally just follow the instruction suffices. However if something goes wrong, knowing what is going on under the hood helps you to diagnose the issue.

### How to use `mylatexformat`? [basic instruction]

Say, you have a normal LaTeX document `a.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  1+2 &= 3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Assume `a.tex` does not contain space, or special character such as `%#{}~`.

First you execute `pdftex -ini -jobname=a "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx a.tex`. This will generate `a.fmt`. <sub>(the output `.fmt` file name is specified by `-jobname`, if not specified default to `mylatexformat.fmt`, nevertheless using `-jobname` the same as file name is less likely to cause errors)</sub>

Then you execute `pdftex "&a" a.tex`. This will generate `a.pdf` as usual.

#### Remark on reading `mylatexformat` package documentation

- `-ini` and `-initialize` (as suggested in `mylatexformat` documentation) is the same thing. But **`-initialize` doesn't work in TeXLive**, so use `-ini` is safer.
- Its instruction on writing `"""abc.tex"""` on the command-line is for Windows only, on Linux/Bash you need
  `"\"abc.tex\""`. (basically pass the file name wrapped in *one layer of double quote* to TeX)
- `&a` specifies that the format in file `a.fmt` should be used.
- If the first line of `a.tex` is `%&a`, then the 2nd command you don't need to explicitly specify `"&a"` on the command-line,
  anything such as `pdftex a.tex` or `pdflatex a.tex` will suffice. Nevertheless [**this method does not work with LuaTeX**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622002/lualatex-not-parsing-first-line-format-in-texlive).

### How to use `mylatexformat`? [advanced instruction]

#### Use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX

Replace `pdftex` with `xetex` or `luahbtex` respectively. Furthermore you need to replace the preloaded format name `&pdflatex` with `&xelatex` or `&lualatex`.

You can tell that `xelatex` and `lualatex` executable are just `xetex` and `luahbtex` with `xelatex.fmt` and `lualatex.fmt` formats preloaded by seeing what it prints out at the beginning.

Furthermore note that first-line `%&a` (as written in package documentation) will not work in LuaTeX.

For example:

```
% a.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\csname endofdump\endcsname
\usepackage{unicode-math}  % incompatible with precompiled preamble, see below
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  1+2 &= 3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Then in the shell:

```bash
luahbtex -ini -jobname=a "&lualatex" mylatexformat.ltx a.tex
luahbtex "&a" a.tex
```

This only speed up by a small amount, in my experience for an almost-empty document it is 0.6s → 0.4s.

#### Do not precompile the whole preamble

If some part of the preamble either:

- changes frequently (so you don't want to include into the format), or
- relies on `\jobname` (for example `\usepackage{currfile}`, or [`pythontex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279845/250119)), or
- is incompatible with TeX format, such as `\usepackage{unicode-math}` or `\usepackage{fontspec}`, <sub>(see "two other classes of things that can not be dumped." in [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83486/250119))</sub>

  - For some reason for LuaLaTeX even `tikz` is incompatible.
  - I don't see any easy way to easily tell what package is compatible and what is not, you will just have to try including/excluding it.

then you must exclude it from the preamble.

To do that use `\csname endofdump\endcsname` (the spelling must be exactly like that) -- see `mylatexformat` documentation for
more details. Using this instead of `\endofdump` makes sure the file is compilable (the line is simply ignored) if `mylatexformat`/precompiled preamble is not used (i.e. the file is compiled the normal way).

### What is precompiled preamble/format?

Basically, it is just using TeX's INITeX feature to speed up processing of a fixed preamble part.

TeX supports generating *formats* that can be loaded later.
Refer to TeX by Topic chapter 33 "TeX and the Outside World" for some details.

<sub>(Reading TeXbook might be a bit confusing, just keep in mind that typing anything on the command-line is equivalent to typing it on the `**` first line in the TeX prompt.)</sub>

In short:

> A format file (usually with extension .fmt) is a compact dump of TEX’s internal structures. Loading a format file takes a considerably shorter time than would be needed for loading the font information and the macros that constitute the format.

So you can "define some commands, dump the internal state to a file", then when you "load" that file it's "as if" the commands have been defined similar to at the time how the format was dumped.

For an example:

```
% preamble.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\dump

% a.tex
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  1+2 &= 3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

In the shell execute `pdftex -ini "&pdflatex" preamble.tex`, this will

- start with the existing `pdflatex.fmt` format <sub>(might be at `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt` depends on operating system etc.)</sub>
- execute from file `preamble.tex`
- when `\dump` is executed generates file `preamble.fmt`.

The `-ini` is needed to enable the `\dump` command.

After that if `pdftex "&preamble" a.tex` is executed (this means "execute `a.tex` with preloaded format `preamble.fmt`") it will generate `a.pdf` with the correct content. <sub>(For an analogue, `pdftex "&pdflatex" a.tex` is equivalent to `pdflatex a.tex`)</sub>

### What does `mylatexformat` package do?

As you can see above, it's rather inconvenient to have to split the file into separate `preamble.tex`.
So `mylatexformat` allow you to put them in the same file and it will automatically detect the split between the preamble and the main file.

### How does `mylatexformat` work (regarding the command-line)?

There's 2 steps -- generating the format, and using the format.

In the first step, apart from `-jobname`, the command-line is:

`pdftex -ini "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx a.tex`

Because of historical reasons, it's made such that (almost) anything put on the command-line is equivalent to typing it to the first
line of `**` prompt. So you can also run `pdftex -ini` then on `**` prompt type in `&pdflatex mylatexformat.ltx a.tex`, both are equivalent.

Most of this is familiar. Recall that `pdftex -ini "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx` will start with preloaded format `pdflatex.fmt`
and execute content of file `mylatexformat.ltx`. However, the additional `a.tex` will be **put on the input stream**.

At the very end of `mylatexformat.ltx`, after redefining `\begin` etc. there's

```
%% Trick lookahead to allow mylatex.ltx and the document filename to be
%% given on the same command line. (initex &latex mylatex.ltx {abc.tex})
\expandafter\input\endinput%
\endinput
```

so effectively <sub>(some TeX programming knowledge is needed)</sub> `\input a.tex` is executed. See also [wipet's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/672107/250119).

That's why it's useful to pass another pair of quotes in the command-line.

For other details of the implementation (how it separates the preamble from the document) read the documentation.

### More speedup by unzipping the format file

Refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708544/250119.

This can save 0.1 to 0.2 seconds each compilation.