# mylatexformat and pythontex

Tags: format-files, pythontex

I use `mylatexformat` to easily build format files. Consider the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
% This is file t.tex
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Then, I run `pdflatex -ini -jobname="myfmt" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx """t.tex"""` to get `myfmt.fmt`.

Now, I have another file:

```
%&myfmt
\documentclass{NoMatterItIsNotReadAnyway}
% This is s.tex
\begin{document}
\begin{pygments}{python}
def foo():
    return 'bar'
\end{pygments}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, the format `myfmt.fmt` is loaded and it comes with `pythontex` preloaded. A `pdf` file is produced: compilation is fine. Then, I run `pythontex s.tex`: no warnings. Then, I compile once again `s.tex`. Unfortunately, the python code does not show up in the `pdf` file. All I get is `?? PythonTeX ??`.

The `log` tells me that

```
Package PythonTeX Warning: Non-existent Pygments content on input line 8.
```

and also

```
No file pythontex-files-myfmt/myfmt.pytxmcr
```

So I guess there me be some "hard coded" filenames and directory names defined when the format is created.

Is there a workaround so that I could use `mylatexformat` with `pythontex` the way I showed here?

Comment: `pythontex` uses `\jobname` to create a directory name for saving output, among other things. You are probably running into the issues with precompiling discussed in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling/83486#83486). When I use `pythontex` with a precompiled preamble, I generally load it separately, after the precompiled material. I don't know if that's possible with `mylatexformat`.

Comment: @G.Poore Thanks for your comments. Would it be possible to define those filenames based on `\jobname` with some `etoolbox` hooks (`\AtEndPreamble` or `\AfterEndPreamble`). I could probably hack something if I knew where to look. The reason why I'd like to avoid `usepackag`ing `pythontex` after precompiled material is that I'd like to avoid my users the pain to do it.

Comment: It's possible to use `\setpythontexoutputdir{<dirname>}` to set the directory manually. The bigger problem is that the temp files using `\jobname` are opened immediately when the package is loaded, and that breaks with precompiling. I suppose it might be possible to reopen them at the end of the preamble, to try to correct for the file issues caused by precompiling. The `*.pytxcode` file would be the one to worry about (unless you're using `depythontex`).

Comment: @G.Poore Would it be possible to defer the opening after the preamble (with the hooks of `etoolbox`)?

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround with `etoolbox` `\AtEndPreamble` (for some reason, a simple `\AtBeginDocument` does not work, producing a file named `@codefile=s.pytxcode`).

```
\documentclass{article}
% This is file t.tex
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{pythontex}}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

It is only a workaround as `pythontex` is *not* precompiled.

Comment: I have some ideas about how to support proper precompiling, but it will likely be more complicated than a simple etoolbox patch. I've opened an [issue at GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/76). I will be spending much of December and January working on the next version of PythonTeX, and should be able to have a fix in the next release.