# pdflatex with precompiling does not support .Tex file with Chinese filename

Tags: pdftex, cjk

First I am sure, pdflatex can compile Tex file with Chinese file name without problem. For example, the Tex source content is as follows

```
\documentclass[UTF8,hyperref]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
    中文
\end{document}
```

save it as a file named "中文.tex" and run

```
pdflatex 中文.tex
```

everything is OK.

Now, in order to speed up the compilation, we make pre-compilation according to [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling). That is to edit a file named "pre.tex" whose content is as follows

```
\documentclass[UTF8,hyperref]{ctexart}
```

and run

```
pdflatex -ini -jobname="pre" "&pdflatex pre.tex\dump"
```

to generate a .fmt file called "pre.fmt"

now, we use this precompiled .fmt file in out tex source like

```
%& pre
\begin{document}
    中文
\end{document}
```

if we save it as a file named "en.tex", and `pdflatex en.tex` works fine.
But if we save it as a file named "中文.tex", then `pdflatex 中文.tex` will show errors like

[image]

**What is wrong here? why precompile doesn't support Tex file with Chinese file name?**

I upload the file "中文.tex" [download here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00450553119767846023)

Comment: Do you type the name of the file? Can you try typing `pdflatex`, and then drag&drop the file on the Terminal window? It looks like your terminal doesn't see the Chinese characters, so what you type is not what it needs to see. I'd try that. Don't forget the space after `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Alenanno drag is not working.

Comment: @Alenanno I add a link to my file, maybe you would like to test it

Comment: Well obviously pdflatex did open the file as it found the `%& pre` file and loaded the format but then wasn't able to continue. You should report this to the tex live mailing list. (But I would avoid such file names. There are not very portable.).

Comment: Did you try running `pdftex -format=pre 中文.tex`, instead of relying on the `%&` line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see the cause here

```
\edef\x{中文.tex}\show\x
\documentclass[UTF8,hyperref]{ctexart}
\edef\x{中文.tex}\show\x
\begin{document}
    中文
\end{document}
```

Compare the two `\show`

Initially the bytes are all essentially inert and so the filename gets passed to the filesystem and would work, but after the class has been loaded the bytes have been made active and given definitions that enable *typesetting* of the characters but this means they expand to the wrong thing for the filename.

---

I don't have all the fonts to fully test this but I think it works if you change your format template to

```
\documentclass[UTF8,hyperref]{ctexart}

% set high chars active at start of job
% After the commandline has been read, but before Tex starts reading the
% file contents, the tokens in \everyjob are run. 
% This loop sets every character between 127 and 255 to be catcode 13
% "active" which is the catcode they normally have after inputenc package
% or the ctexart class code.
\everyjob{{\count0=127
\loop
\global\catcode\count0=13
\ifnum\count0<255
\advance\count0 1
\repeat
}}

% set high chars inactive now for filename reading
% This loop sets every character between 127 and 255 to be catcode 12
% "other" which is the normal catcode for punctuation. this means that
% no special interpretation is done and the filename works as in a normal 
% format (where high characters are also not active until inputenc or
% similar is loaded. 
% Unlike the previous loop which is delayed in \everyjob
% This loop is executed here to make characters safe before the \dump
{\count0=127
\loop
\global\catcode\count0=12
\ifnum\count0<255
\advance\count0 1
\repeat
}
```

So that the 8bit characters are not active until `\everyjob` is run, after the filename has been read.

Comment: Well, that's very interesting code. What's the `e` in `\edef`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. But I don't understand how to do this "use \string or \unexpanded to prevent expansion on the commandline"

Comment: @Alenanno `\edef` is expanded def, macros in the replacement text get expanded at definition time, needed here to show that 中文 expands to typesetting commands in the second case

Comment: @user15964 I have been off line, do you still need an example? (not sure how well my cygwin deals with filenames of that form, but I could try...)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh, so that is command in linux right? But I am currently under windows using CMD. So the problem is pdflatex.exe not terminal, right? I think this brings another interesting question: what is the safest compile command line in windows CMD or linux terminal in cases of there will be nonstandard file name? I am not in a hurry, you can comment back when you have spare time. Thank you so much

Comment: @user15964 I've updated the answer with something I think works (but I get errors on my system anyway about missing fonts so not fully tested) Please report back if it works!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wow, this is awesome! It works! Thank you so much! But I don't understand your code. Would you like to add more explanations?

Comment: @user15964 I expanded the comments in the code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, still beyond my comprehension. But I think I'll just stop here, thank you very much!