# Biber ignores \addbibresource when using format (fmt) file

Tags: biber, format-files

I am creating a format file using `mylatexformat`. This allows me to precompile my (extremely lengthy preamble, shortening compile time.

However, biber does not respond to `addbibresource`, complaining either

```
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for '...'
```

or, if no bibresource at all was included in the format file:

```
WARN - No data sources defined!
```

How can I `addbibresource` *and* have a precompiled preamble?

## Minimum working example

### foo.tex

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}
\endofdump

\addbibresource{foo2.bib}
\begin{document}
This is just a test. With a citation: \textcite{test1}.
And another: \textcite{test2}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### foo.bib

```
@article{test1,
    title = {Some title},
    journaltitle = {Some journal},
    author = {Rob, London},
    date = {2018-01-01}
}
```

### foo2.bib

```
@article{test2,
    title = {Some title 2},
    journaltitle = {Some journal},
    author = {Rob, London},
    date = {2018-01-02}
}
```

If I first compile the preamble using:

```
pdftex -ini -jobname="foo" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx foo.tex
```

Then I comment (or delete) the preamble and add `%&foo` as the first line:

### foo.tex (after compiling preamble):

```
%&foo
\addbibresource{foo2.bib}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
This is just a test. With a citation: \textcite{test1}.
And another: \textcite{test2}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

biber will now complain:

```
> biber foo
.
.
.
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'test2' (section 0)
```

Comment: On which operating system are you? You don't need to remove the preamble. You can make `pdftex` use your format using `pdftex -fmt="foo" foo.tex`. But bibliography files where never a problem for me.

Comment: Seems as though everything in the preamble of the `%&foo` file is ignored. You can see this if you add an obviously undefined command like `\zzzfooo`: No error is produced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an `\endofdump`

```
%&foo
\endofdump
\addbibresource{foo2.bib}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
This is just a test. With a citation: \textcite{test1}.
And another: \textcite{test2}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you use your precompiled format all code in the preamble before `\endofdump` is ignored. You can verify this by calling an obviously undefined command (say `\zzz`) in the preamble: It will only cause an error if it is written after `\endofdump`.

The [documentation of contains `mylatexformat`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mylatexformat/mylatexformat.pdf) contains a verbatim copy of the comments in [`mylatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mylatex) which has a similar limitation

> The ‘mylatex’ format normally skips the whole preamble (believing it to be pre-loaded) and so such new commands do not take effect.

The solution in `mylatex` is to add a comment with the content `mylatex` (i.e. the line `% mylatex`) to the preamble. For `mylatexformat` the trick is `\endofdump`.

Comment: Isn't this also what the hint in your answer stated? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377033/35864

Comment: Yes! Historical me has outsmarted present-day me. Not for the first time. Thanks for linking back to that.