# Can I make something like a 'snapshot' of the loaded packages?

Tags: packages, compiling, preamble

Currently may document is not very big, however when using Texworks and have a look at the output prompt what is showing what latex currently does when compiling, nearly 90% of the compilation time it is loading all of the packages and styles mentioned in  the preamble.

Could there be a way in dramatically speed up the process of compiling in let him load all of the packages and options and save this 'state' in some way? Looking at the externalize of tikzpicture he compile the tikz code once when something has changed and then pack it in a .pdf

Is there a way doing the same with loaded packages? I would say the packages will not change after each compile so reload them every time is redundant?

I hope you see what I mean, but maybe I am fault here as still being very nooby.

Comment: You may be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8791/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79493/35864.

Comment: initex does/did that, See https://texfaq.org/FAQ-initex