# pre-compiling long document preamble

Tags: compiling, preamble

I have several long documents (500-1000+ pages), where the pre-amble is itself rather lengthy (say, 15-25 packages being loaded, with multiple option tweaks, lots of custom functions, etc, etc). When compiling (I normally use MikTeX, but observe the same with TeXlive), a fair chunk of time comes from reading in the pre-amble, before getting to contents of the document itself.

In browsing around it seems there are methods for pre-compling the preamble (e.g., [Ultrafast PDFLaTeX with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling)), but everything I've found applies to PDFTex or LuaTex, but I haven't found anything that might work with my normal build sequence: .tex -> .dvi -> .ps -> .pdf.

Perhaps it isn't possible, but it would be a major time saver if I could pre-compile the preamble for these big docs, since the preamble isn't changing (typically) between compiles.

Any options?

Comment: any preamble saving format technique that works with pdflatex will work with latex (but for 99% of documents pdflatex _is_ the normal build sequence these days, is there a particular reason you still use dvi?)

Comment: see for example latexformat or mylatexformat which can make custom latex formats with a preloaded preamble (there are examples in the post that you reference)

Comment: Thanks very much. As for why I use .dvi ->, simple. I do a lot with PostScript (images, PSTricks, etc).