# Speedup preamble compilation

Tags: compiling

My document takes 5sec to compile (draft mode), and most of the time is spent on the preamble. This is due to all the packages that I use. Is there a way to precompile the preamble to speedup compilation?

Comment: mylatex (https://ctan.org/pkg/mylatex) or mylatexformat. But it could also help to simply clean up the preamble. Or are you sure that you really need all the packages?

Comment: Yeah. I added your answer to the question.

Comment: please don't add answers to question sit destroys the question and answer format of the site

Answer (score 3):

- Based on Ulrike's comment.
- The package [`mylatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mylatex) from [David Carlisle](https://ctan.org/author/carlisle) addresses this problem.
- But according to [Ultrafast PDFLaTeX with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493) (2012), David recommends the [`mylatexformat`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mylatexformat) package from a different author: *"My truly ancient `mylatex` files on ctan do this or there is a newer version of that with additional features and better maintained: `mylatexformat`"*.

> The file `mylatex.ltx` permits you to create a format that pre-loads a
> set of package files (and/or other macros) that you regularly use. In
> some circumstances, this can be a great advantage (though on an
> ordinarily fast modern computer on the desktop, gains will be limited)

Comment: @david-carlisle In case you are willing to improve this answer.