# line spacing in the list of algorithms(2e) disappears with newfloat option of minted

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, minted, algorithm2e

I noticed some really weird interaction between `algorithms2e` and the option `newfloat` of the `minted` package.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms % here the spacing is not correct

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: incorrect spacing]

Whereas if I invert the order of the loading of the packages the list of algorithms return to behave normally

```
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
```

[image: correct spacing]

I must necessarily load first `algorithms2e` because [I dump my preamble to speed up compilation time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling) since I load a ton of packages for typesetting my book, and I can't dump `minted` because it seems it doesn't get along with the cache option.

Is there a way to avoid this annoying behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be an incompatibility between algorithm2e and newfloat package, so it seems to be sufficient to load the newfloat package before the algorithm2e package:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ...I've send an e-mail to both maintainers, the one from the newfloat package has already answered that she/he will fix it this week-end.

Answer (score 1):

Some patchwork corrects the problem:

- Writing `algorithm`s to the `<jobname>.lol` rather than `<jobname>.loa`.
- Update `\listofalgorithms` to load `<jobname>.lol` rather than `<jobname>.loa`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\makeatletter
% Write algorithm to <jobname>.lol rather than <jobname>.loa
\renewcommand{\algocf@list}{lol}%
% Let \listofalgorithms load <jobname>.lol rather than <jobname>.loa
\patchcmd{\listofalgocfs}% <cmd>
  {loa}% <search>
  {lol}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution resolve the spacing problems but it raises another one: now I can't distinguish between the list of pseudocode and the list of code, but there is only one list for both type of object. This a patch, not a solution