# How can I convince emacs/auctex to parse precompiled header files?

Tags: auctex, ini

AUCTeX automatically parses my headers and determines what packages I use, making adjustments accordingly. For example, it knows when I've used cleveref and changes the available types of references when I type `C-c )` accordingly.

However, if I [precompile my preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling), AUCTeX does not know what packages I am using. Is there a way that I can set a variable to convince it to parse the header files, which are never included explicitly (except via the special comment `%&preamble`)?

It would be a bonus if I could also convince AUCTeX to precompile the header, which I currently do from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can achieve what you're looking for by setting a variable.  Not tested, but I can think of the following:

1. Start Emacs, open a .tex file so that AUCTeX is loaded.  Then do <kbd>M-x TeX-auto-generate RET</kbd>.  When asked for a TeX file, enter the `preamble.tex`.  When asked for an AUTO directory, take `/path/to/your-tex-file/auto` or the directory which is stored in `TeX-auto-private`.  Emacs should parse and save a `preamble.el` there.
2. In your .tex file, add the following line to the file local variables:
   `%%% eval: (TeX-run-style-hooks "preamble")`.
   The entire block should look like this:

   ```
   %%% Local Variables:
   %%% mode: latex
   %%% TeX-master: t
   %%% eval: (TeX-run-style-hooks "preamble")
   %%% End:
   ```
3. Now restart Emacs and load your .tex file and see if this works by hitting <kbd>C-h e</kbd>: You should see if AUCTeX style files were loaded.

For the bonus question, I'd suggest you try to add a command for preamble pre-compilation to [`TeX-command-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Selecting-a-Command.html).

Comment: As you say, this is not just setting a variable. But it worked for me! Many thanks for the guidance. I accepted the answer.