# Auto-Compile after any modification in WinEdt

Tags: compiling, automation, winedt

Is there any way to make WinEdt to automatically re-compile after any modification in TeX file? I know that it is possible to do it using third-party codes like it is explained here:
[Why can Bakoma process .tex files so fast?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33615/why-can-bakoma-process-tex-files-so-fast)

but, I am wondering if there is any way to do it with WinEdt itself?

Comment: Well... there are other LaTeX editors, more friendly and comfortable to use than WinEdt. I used long time ago, but now I prefer TeXMaker or TeXStudio. 
I'm afraid I'm not understanding your question right, what you want is to compile again after modifying or recompile automatically as you've made ​​changes?

Comment: Yes, I want to recompile automatically as I modify the TeX file in WinEdt.

Comment: BTW. I also tried many other LaTeX editors if not all of them and I prefer WinEdt. IMO its customizability is incomparable with any other LaTeX editor!

Comment: A recompilation "after every modification" is not a good idea: there could be unfinished environments or commands and you would get a lot of errors. You could tell winedt to recompile when you save the file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: How can I do this (making winedt to recompile after saving)?

Comment: @M0HS3N well in TeXMaker, I can edit my documents, and pressing F1 it saves itself and later recompile the file. That works fine for me. If you feel comfortable with that it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[To get this off the unanswered list]

Since it's almost 8 years that I collaborate in WinEdt development, I can tell you that the answer is **NO**, nothing can be done from within WinEdt to accomplish your needs.

If you really want to do something like this, you have to use an external tool like AutoIt, as in the question you've mentioned.